# Split text using strtok without deleting the delim c++

Tags: c++, string

How can I split a text into tokens using strtok without deleting the delim?
I want just to split at their place.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `strtok` does the splitting by replacing the delimiter with a '\0'. Without doing that, no splitting would happen.

You could, however, create a function that did splitting kind of like `strtok` does, but by finding where the string should be split and (for example) allocating storage and copying the characters up to the delimiter into that storage. `strcspn` or `strpbrk` would probably be a useful start at this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use boost? [boost::algorithm::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) does exactly what you want.

You can, of course, write one yourself; it's not like split is complicated: (Note: I have not actualy tested this)

```
std::wstring source(L"Test\nString");
std::vector<std::wstring> result;
std::wstring::iterator start, end;
start = source.begin();
end = std::find(source.begin(), source.end(), L'\n');
for(; end != source.end(); start = end, end = std::find(end, source.end(), L'\n'))
    result.push_back(std::wstring(start, end));
result.push_back(std::wstring(start, end));
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple don't use strtok.

Use the C++ stream operator.
The getline() function can be used with an extra parameter that defines the end of line token.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string         text("This is text; split by; the semicolon; that we will split into bits.");
    std::stringstream   textstr(text);

    std::string               line;
    std::vector<std::string>  data;
    while(std::getline(textstr,line,';'))
    {
        data.push_back(line);
    }
}
```

With a tiny bit more work we can even get the STL algorithms to pay their part we just need to define how a token is streamed. To do this just define a token class (or struct) then define the operator>> that reads up to the token separator.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Token
{
    std::string data;
    operator std::string() const { return data;}
};
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream,Token& data)
{
    return std::getline(stream,data.data,';');
}

int main()
{
    std::string         text("This is text; split by; the semicolon; that we will split into bits.");
    std::stringstream   textstr(text);

    std::vector<std::string>  data;

    // This statement does the work of the loop from the last example.
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Token>(textstr),
              std::istream_iterator<Token>(),
              std::back_inserter(data)
             );

    // This just prints out the vector to the std::cout just to illustrate it worked.
    std::copy(data.begin(),data.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout,"\n"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The behavior of `strtok` is that it replaces the delimiter with a NUL character.  This behavior is not configurable.  To return each substring, including the delimiter, you will have to find a function other than `strtok`, or else combine `strtok` with some of your own processing.

Answer (score 0):

If your libc implementation has it, take a look at strsep (3)